# Multiple CSS background colors that is in parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website I am creating with several background-colors. I know I can do this with an image, but because I am creating a responsive site, I do not want to use an image.

In the sample, you can see that the blue, red, green colors show up at the beginning.
But when you click show, they disappear behind the orange layer, when toggled.

So the question is,

How can I keep the backgrounds relative inside the #wrap2 div with CSS when the #wraps are toggled?

I need this to work in IE8 and above.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/MSZXa/)

Here is the CSS:

```css
body {margin:0;padding:0;background:#ccc;}
#wrap1{width:100%;height:200px;postion:absolute;background:orange;display:none;}
#wrap2{width:100%;height:200px;postion:absolute;}

#bg1{width:100%;height:50px;background:#0099cc;position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:50px}
#bg2{width:100%;height:50px;background:#990000;position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:100px}
#bg3{width:100%;height:50px;background:#99cc00;position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:150px;}
#logo{width:25%;height:100px;background:yellow;margin:2%;float:left;}
```

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrap1">hello one</div>
<div id="wrap2">hello two<button id="showcontact">show</button>
<div id="bg1">hi div1</div>
<div id="bg2">hi div2</div>
<div id="bg3">hi div3</div>
<div id="logo">logo</div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#showcontact").click(function () {
    $("#wrap1").toggle();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try making #wrap2 position:relative. And fix the typos too.

Comment: can you explain better what you want it to look like? i don't quite understand what you want the end result to be

Comment: For #wrap1 and #wrap2, you have *postion* instead of *position*

Comment: check this out. i did it with an image, but would rather use css. http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/WYYES/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neps is correct. `position: relative` on #wrap2. http://jsfiddle.net/MSZXa/22/

Comment: I see you also removed the position:absolute from #wrap1 - thanks for the jsfiddle example!

Comment: @Neps - thanks also, I changed what you said, didnt notice those typo's at first. As 2pha did, I had to remove the positioning on #wrap1